# Need to create a decoder that creates a record out of data in parent level and attaches it to all the children records in elm

Tags: json, elm

I have a json like this:

```
{
  "username": "john",
  "email": "john@gmail.com",
  "items": [
     { 
        "id": "id 1"
     },
     { 
        "id": "id 2" 
     }
  ]
}
```

I need to decode it into `List Item`. Item being a record like this.

```
type alias Item =
    { id : String
    , user : User
    }

type alias User =
    { username : String
    , email : String
    }
```

I want to extract username and email from top level of json. Then create a `User` record out of it and then put that user inside every `Item` record in `List Item`.

I understand it could be done by using `Decode.andThen`, but can't make it work.

For decoding I am using [json-decode-pipeline](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline/3.0.0/Json-Decode-Pipeline).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly do this with `andThen`. Here is an example using standard JSON decoding (no need for json-decode-pipeline).

First let's create a User decoder. This is pretty straight forward:

```elm
userDecoder : Decoder User
userDecoder =
    map2 User
        (field "username" string)
        (field "email" string)
```

Now, let's create an Item decoder, but let's create it as a function which accepts a User value that we can place onto the `user` field. You'll see why in a minute:

```elm
itemDecoder : User -> Decoder Item
itemDecoder user =
    map2 Item
        (field "id" string)
        (succeed user)
```

Now we can create the top level Items decoder. You'll first decode the user, then pass that into the itemDecoder when building the list:

```elm
itemsDecoder : Decoder (List Item)
itemsDecoder =
    userDecoder
        |> andThen (\user ->
            field "items" (list (itemDecoder user)))
```

This can be written a little more succinctly like this:

```elm
itemsDecoder : Decoder (List Item)
itemsDecoder =
    userDecoder
        |> andThen (field "items" << list << itemDecoder)
```

[Here is a working example on ellie-app.com](https://embed.ellie-app.com/x8dfLS6NH9a1/1).

Comment: Hi @chad What if I have a list of these users as well (which have items under them). How can I combine these items inside users into single list of items. I tried a bunch of things, but not working. Sorry to bother you again.

Comment: That is as simple as using `list itemsDecoder`. [Here is an example](https://ellie-app.com/xb3pB4jFMda1/0)

Comment: Yes thats what I tried doing. But its not fitting for my API as it returns list of list of items, Like this: `[ [item1, item2], [item3, item4] ]` while the previous was returning, like this: `[ item1, item2, item3, item4 ]`. Is there a way to [concatMap](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/List#concatMap) it on the fly?

Comment: Sounds like `list itemsDecoder |> map List.concat` is what you're looking for. [Here is an updated example](https://ellie-app.com/xb3pB4jFMda1/1)